# HashMap contains method

Tags: hashmap, dart

I have defined a custom operator in my object:

```dart
class CharNode {
  String char = "x";
  String color = "#000000";
  String backgroundColor = "none";

  CharNode(this.char) { }

  bool operator ==(CharNode other) {        
    return (other.char == char && other.backgroundColor == other.backgroundColor && other.color == color);
  }
}
```

And it works when I compare two CharNodes (example):

```dart
CharNode cn1 = new CharNode("A");
CharNode cn2 = new CharNode("A");
print((cn1 == cn2).toString());
```

which prints true.

The problem is with HashMap (example) and finding an object in it:

```dart
HashMap<CharNode, int> map = new HashMap<CharNode, int>();
map[cn1] = 0;
print((map.contains(cn2)).toString());
```

which prints false.

The question is: How to make HashMap use my custom operator? Do I have to use forEach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to defining equality, you must also provide a [hashCode](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:core.Object#id_hashCode) implementation.

As the [HashMap docs](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:collection.HashMap#id_hashCode) state:

> The keys of a HashMap must have consistent Object.operator== and
>   hashCode implementations. This means that the == operator must define
>   a stable equivalence relation on the keys (reflexive, symmetric,
>   transitive, and consistent over time), and that hashCode must be the
>   same for objects that are considered equal by ==.

Comment: So the problem is in hashCode equality? Can I set the hashCode manually?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you need to do. See http://pchalin.blogspot.ca/2014/04/defining-equality-and-hashcode-for-dart.html for more info.

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't set the `hashCode` manually, you override the `hashCode` getter.